# As the service object to display a message in the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I did a service object to:
app/services/result_service.rb

```
class ResultService
  def initialize(number_of_errors)
    if number_of_errors == 0
      flash[:success] = "0 error"
      card.update_review_date
    elsif number_of_errors == 1
      flash[:error] = "1 error"
    elsif number_of_errors == 2
      flash[:error] = "2 errors"
    elsif number_of_errors == 3
      flash[:error] = "3 errors"
    else number_of_errors == 4
      flash[:error] = "4 or more of errors"
    end
  end
end
```

It handles incoming parameter from the controller.

If I leave the flash messages as I pointed out above, it will generate an error:

```
undefined local variable or method `flash' for #<ResultService:0x007fd6488bf080>
```

How to bring a flash message? 
I suggested that this can be done through the views helper. 
How to do it?

Comment: Flash is for the controllers, and what you have there, looks like it belongs in a controller.

Comment: Yes, of course I understand where in case to do it. And how to bring more of my view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit hard to give an ideal solution for this question, because I don't know how `ResultService` is used. Anyway this solution should work for you:

```
class ResultService
  def initialize(number_of_errors, controller)
    if number_of_errors == 0
      controller.flash[:success] = "0 error"
      card.update_review_date
    elsif number_of_errors == 1
      controller.flash[:error] = "1 error"
    elsif number_of_errors == 2
      controller.flash[:error] = "2 errors"
    elsif number_of_errors == 3
      controller.flash[:error] = "3 errors"
    else number_of_errors == 4
      controller.flash[:error] = "4 or more of errors"
    end
  end
end

# somewhere in controller
ResultService.new(number_of_errors, self)
```

This approach is called [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

Comment: Sorry, I might be wrong, but I have a gut feeling that `ResultService` has wrong design. Initialiser looks a bit weird to me, but it might be just my personal taste.

Comment: Usually the initialiser set the initial state of the object. In this case initialiser changes the state of `card` object (is that model?) and passes the flash message to controller.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but you can use special method:

```
pluralize(object.errors.count, "error")
```

Or in your case with notice:

```
pluralize(number_of_errors, 'thing')
```

Comment: Sorry Eugene, I do not understand how to do it applies to my case?

Comment: Yes, of course I understand where in case to do it. And how to bring more of my view?

Comment: Awww I thought the problem was you handle a lot of cases for error text which has dependencies from count of errors.

Comment: Я вас понял. Но проблема встала как раз в выводе в представление. Так как сервисный объект "тупой", то из него не возможно сделать ни render, ни flash.

Comment: На сколько я понял, вызов notice и flash валидны только через контроллы.

Comment: Да, в этом плане согласен с Вами. Евгений, есть у Вас мысли или идеи как можно вывести сообщения в views? Мне подсказали, что это возможно сделать через helper views. Что думаете на этот счёт?

Comment: Используйте традиционный вывод ерроров)

'<% if @product.errors.any? %>'
'<%= pluralize(@product.errors.count, "error") %>'
'<% @product.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>'
'<%= message %>'
'<% end %>'

Comment: Нет, нет, мне надо чтобы из сервисного объекта шёл вывод в views. Переделать и убрать сервисный объект не могу.

Comment: Попробуй заинклудить флеш 'ActionDispatch::Flash' в твой файл

Comment: Не, не прошёл фокус. В документации так нельзя: https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api#other-middlewares